# Apache Chemistry is retired

Tags: apache-chemistry

Apache Chemistry is retired. So what are other implementation which is close to Apache Chemistry. Apache Chemistry doesn't support Java 17 / JakartaEE 10.  So looking for replacement

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apache Chemistry CMIS jars are working fine with Java 11. But the same jars are not working with Java 17/Jakarta EE 10. Looking for solution to fix this issue